# How to call a template?

Tags: django

How can I call the the about.html from the following index.html? What to add to urls and views?
All the html files including about and index are collected in the project/static folder.

```
# This is part of the index.html, where I want to call the about.html          
<div class="card-footer">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
</div>

# Here is the project/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app1 import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.index),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: You should not think in terms of templates, but in terms of views. If you want to make an `about` view, you can use the `{% url 'name-of-about-view' %}` template tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in one html file and want to open another html file you can put something like this in your html file:

```html
<a href="{% url 'about' %}">  Go to About  </a>
```

This will create a clickable link on the words Go to About. You can then position this anywhere you want on your page. In your urlpatterns you would need to make a new path like this

```py
path('about', view.AboutView.as_view(), name='about')
```

Within your views.py you have to make a class called AboutView using templateView and put the name of your html file as template_name like this:

```py
from django.views.generic.base import *

class AboutView(TemplateView):
     template_name = "about.html"
```

Let me know if you need more help understanding this code or want to do something else

Comment: Hey did my answer work for you? If it did can you checkmark it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Agent,                                                                                                        After the above corrections I got the following error message:                                Using the URLconf defined in simsite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

       'admin/
       about [name='about']
       ^static/(?P<path>.*)$'                                                                                        The current path, /about, didn't match any of these.

Comment: My IDE says the following is not used: from django.views.generic.base import *

Comment: It does not work for me. I can send my project to be checked. Please note that I am not a software engineer. This is a hubby and learning process for me.

Comment: @Fardin Did you add the second item into your urlpatterns.py

Answer (score 0):

add about url in your urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.index),
path('about/', views.about, name="about"),
]
```

add about views in your views.py file

```
def about(request):
    # render your template here
```

in index.html

```
<div class="card-footer">
     <a href="{% url 'about' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
</div>
```